# Where I will get kGraphURI and kScopes for implementing Azure B2c Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I need to implement B2C login and signup for my application. I have downloaded the code using below link from GitHub.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal

In this it show that I need some constant to configure.

```
let kTenantName = "<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com" // Your tenant name
let kClientID = "<your-client-id>" // Your client ID from the portal when you created your application
let kSignupOrSigninPolicy = "<your-signin-policy>" // Your signup and sign-in policy you created in the portal
let kEditProfilePolicy = "<your-edit-profile-policy>" // Your edit policy you created in the portal
let kGraphURI = "<Your backend API>" // This is your backend API that you've configured to accept your app's tokens
let kScopes: [String] = ["<Your backend API>/demo.read"] // This is a scope that you've configured your backend API to look for.
```

Now where will I get kGraphURI and kScopes ?

Comment: Just based on this, it looks like it expects you have some API already setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this Sample, you need to register both Natvie App and Web API in Azure B2C application.

The backend API means the WebApp/API for which registered in B2C application.

```
kGraphURI = "<Your backend API>" // This is the App ID URI of Web API in the AAD B2C application.

kScopes: [String] = ["<Your backend API>/demo.read"] // This is a scope value which you configured for the Web API in the AAD B2C applicaiton.
```

**For Example:**

```
kGraphURI = "https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/example"

kScopes: [String] = ["https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/example/demo.read"]
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul, Is this answer helpful?